# How to start/stop wind blowing at a specific frame?

Tags: animation, physics

I am running a simulation where I have wind blowing a ball. Very simple stuff. I need the wind to stop blowing after frame 210. I did this earlier but now I can't find where I set the end frame for the wind. It was similar to the start and stop for the animation but it was specific to the wind. I am wondering now if I was seeing things. Help please! Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could keyframe *Strength* value of Wind force field making this value become 0 at some frame.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the force field is not hidden. Select the force field (wind) in the outliner or 3D view. The key frames you set will then show up in the timeline and in the Animation Editor.

Insert a keyframe with a value of zero at frame 210 to stop the wind. If you want the wind to stop abruptly set a keyframe at 209 equal to the value of the keyframe before it.